# Unable to ping server using ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm unable to ping the another server. And i have SSH communication also authenticated. 
Please find the below error

ansible all -m ping  -u ubuntu -i inventory

```
WARNING]: Unhandled error in Python interpreter discovery for host 10.0.3.128: No JSON object could be decoded

[WARNING]: Unhandled error in Python interpreter discovery for host 10.0.3.53: No JSON object could be decoded

An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ImportError: No module named zipfile
[WARNING]: Platform linux on host 10.0.3.128 is using the discovered Python interpreter at /usr/bin/python, but future installation of another Python interpreter could change this. See
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html for more information.

10.0.3.128 | FAILED! => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 10.0.3.128 closed.\r\n",
    "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1574742993.99-111761674559704/AnsiballZ_ping.py\", line 102, in <module>\r\n    _ansiballz_main()\r\n  File \"/home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1574742993.99-111761674559704/AnsiballZ_ping.py\", line 21, in _ansiballz_main\r\n    import zipfile\r\nImportError: No module named zipfile\r\n",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
    "rc": 1
}
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ImportError: No module named zipfile
[WARNING]: Platform linux on host 10.0.3.53 is using the discovered Python interpreter at /usr/bin/python, but future installation of another Python interpreter could change this. See
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html for more information.

10.0.3.53 | FAILED! => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 10.0.3.53 closed.\r\n",
    "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1574742994.0-31022973006547/AnsiballZ_ping.py\", line 102, in <module>\r\n    _ansiballz_main()\r\n  File \"/home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1574742994.0-31022973006547/AnsiballZ_ping.py\", line 21, in _ansiballz_main\r\n    import zipfile\r\nImportError: No module named zipfile\r\n",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
    "rc": 1
}
```

Comment: Please include some traceback, argument `-vvv` as the error stated

Comment: Which version of python are your running on the target host ? Does it meet the [ansible managed node requirements ?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#managed-node-requirements) (i.e. > 2.6) ? Are you sure it is installed/configured correctly ? [`zipfile` is a core python library](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/zipfile.html) and should be available out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Prasanna, go to 10.0.3.128 run python, and try to :

```
import zipfile
```

It seems like either it wasn't compiled with it or it can't find the library so maybe an environment issue. try it as the ansible user

Answer (score 0):

I have got the similar error and resolved it.

After creating the container I used the following command to install python on it:

`apt-get install python-minimal --no-install-recommends`

But, when i got the "ImportError: No module named zipfile" error with ansible ping command, I just got into the container (with lxc-attach) and used:

`apt-get install python`

And then my ansible ping command worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like ansible is not able to find python distribution in the client.
The simplest solution is to tell ansible where to find it in `ansible.cfg`. Just add:

```
[defaults]
...
interpreter_python  = <pyhton path in client>
```

the python path in the client can be found by running:

```
which python
```

or for newer versions (recommended for ansible):

```
which python3
```

like so:

[image]

in most modern Debian based distributions, python is located at `/usr/bin/python3`
that makes the final solution:

```
[defaults]
...
interpreter_python  = /usr/bin/python3
```